# Automatically copy calling phone number in realtime?

Tags: applications, copy-paste

I was looking for an app or an API to copy currently calling phone number to the clipboard where I could paste them to PC directly.

For instance, I'm getting a phone call from (xxx-xxxx-xx) on my android phone and having an app called pigeon that automatically sends any clipboard copied content to PC.

Let's say I want the current calling phone number to be copied and sent to the connected pc to paste in a database searching for said client.

is there a way to achieve that efficiently?

Comment: Have you checked the different `adb logcat` and it's different buffers like `main` `event` `system` if it contains information on incoming calls? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#alternativeBuffers

Comment: @Robert It seems too complicated for the required task

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with [**Tasker**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_IN&gl=US).

1. First, Create a **profile** that triggers this task.
2. Then set, **State** > Call Incoming.
3. Next set, **Task**  > clipboard to **%CNUM** (caller number)

I'm linking a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/xwo9v5/copy_phone_number_to_clipboard_when_incall/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) which has the exact project and an additional getting started with **Tasker** [guide](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/guides.html) for your reference.